# how can I use a color dialog to only apply color to the selected text in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, colors, colordialog

I want to make my color dialog to only apply colors to the selected text how can I do this? thanks.

Comment: what did you try? do you use RichTextBox or normal textbox? how are you showing the ColorDialog right now?

Comment: here is my code, I am using a richtextbox by the way.                 private void toolStripButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog mycolor = new ColorDialog();
         
            {
                if(mycolor.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
               
                {
                   //missing code here 
                }

            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): They support formatting of text selection, as opposed to Label or TextBox

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart=startPosition;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength=length; 
richTextBox1.SelectionColor=myColorDialog.Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

if RTF/HTML doc format, you can easily do this. Check SO other threads. There are few discussing the same.